# How to create your own VPN on an instance and route your other instance through this VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn

I understand that a VPC Amazon instance has the ability to create VPN connections but at a cost of $.05 per hour.  Is it possible to create your own VPN on an instance and then route your other instance through this VPN?  It seems like it would be more cost efficient?  What are the pros/cons?

Answer (score 16):

> I understand that a VPC Amazon instance has the ability...

To clarify, your virtual environment in Amazon VPC is typically referred to as "a VPC," not "a VPC instance."  A "VPC instance" typically refers to an EC2 instance that is provisioned inside a VPC.

A fixed VPN connection can be provisioned from Amazon VPC to a hardware device at your location, and this incurs the $0.05/hour charge (essentially $37.20/mo) you mentioned.  This fee is charged [for as long as the the connection is provisioned on the AWS side](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#B2), whether it is properly configured on your side, and working, or not... because what you are paying for is the use of Amazon's hardware to accommodate the VPN.

To me, this seems like a ridiculously good deal, because my VPC VPN connections -- once established -- pretty much "just work," and if the underlying hardware fails, it seems a reasonable assumption that AWS's proactive monitoring will detect that condition and the hardware would be replaced with no real effort required from me.

But, yes, it's entirely possible to provision a VPN with EC2 instances, but to have a similar level of resiliency compared to what you have if you use the native solution, you would need at least 2 EC2 instances, for failover.

This [Amazon article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5472675506466066) explains how to connect two different VPCs to each other via a VPN using EC2 machines -- since this is not something the native solution supports -- but it does not take much imagination at all to understand how you could use exactly the same logic to tie your corporate network into a VPC with a very comparable design to what's shown here.

The only thing, though, is that the $0.05/hour is cheaper than the price of an on-demand "m1.small" instance, at $0.06/hour, so unless you wanted to prepay for more discounts or try to use "micro" instances to connect your networks together, the native solution provided by VPC seems like a no-brainer.

Understand, though, that the native solution (that is, the VPN service offered by AWS as part of VPC) is only for fixed site-to-site (your-site-to-AWS) connections... it has nothing to do with remote users tunneling into your VPC.  For ad-hoc on-demand connections that provide individual users with the ability to tunnel into your VPC, you'd need to roll your own solution.

Comment: Michael, that is a terrific response, thank you.  So using the AWS VPN solution will allow my instance to connect to outside users/hosts.  However, you suggest that I could not do any tunneling with outside users if I chose to host the VPN server myself?  Why is this?

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around -- AWS's VPN into your VPC (what I referred to as the "native solution") is a fixed, network-to-network connection between their network and your LAN, using what they call a "hardware" (typically a firewall device) VPN connection... it doesn't do on-demand VPN connections from individual machines.  For the ad-hoc, individual remote computer connectivity application, the only option is to roll-your-own, using OpenVPN, pptpd, SSL tunnels, or something similar.  I've updated the last paragraph to clarify that point.  Let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: So I am able to clarify what I would like to know further.  I am more concerned about server to server connections.  For instance my instance will be connected to several servers outside of AWS.  Again from your previous communication you like the built in Amazon VPN.  However their may be up to 30 connections so things could get expensive.  I believe what I am need is a vpn tunnel?  Are there any other cheap, reliable AMIs, other solutions?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, you can stop an EC2 VPN server but cannot stop the native VPN solution. It will go on charging as long as subscribed..

Answer (score 1):

It possible just install OpenVPN on your NAT instance, for example have a look on article:

- [Amazon AWS VPC Setting up OpenVPN server](http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2012/12/amazon-aws-vpc-setting-up-openvpn-server.html)

## Create an Ubuntu instance

This instance will serve as the OpenVPN server. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

### Set up a VPC security group

Before I can create this instance I need to create a new VPC security group for it.
[image]
From the VPN console open Security Groups and click on Create Security Group
[image]
Name it openvpn and associate it with your VPC, then click create.
[image]
Select the Details tab and make not of the group ID, in this case its
sg-cd7c94a2
[image]
Select the Inbound tab and select the SSH rule and click Add Rule.
[image]
Select Custom UDP rule set the port range to 1194 for OpenVPN. Click Add Rule.
[image]
Select Custom TCP rule and enter 943 for the port range click Add Rule.
[image]
Select Custom TCP rule and enter 946 for the port range and click Add Rule
[image]
Select HTTPS and click Add Rule
[image]
Click Apply Rule Changes.
[image]
Here are the Security rules
[image]
Select Subnets and copy the ID of the public subnet, in my case its subnet-4c657627

### Start the instance

Now start the instance
> ec2-run-instances ami-9c78c0f5 -b /dev/sda1=:8:true -k pats-keypair -t t1.micro -s subnet-4c657627 -g sg-cd7c94a2 --private-ip-address 10.0.0.99 --availability-zone us-east-1a
[image]

### Change Source /Dest Check

[image]
From the EC2 console select the newly made instance and right click and select “Change Source / Dest Check”
[image]
Click Yes, Disable

### Give it an elastic IP

[image]
From the VPC console select Elastic IPs and click Allocate New Address
[image]
Make sure its set to VPC and click Yes, Allocate
[image]
Click on associate Address
[image]
Select the instance that was just created and click on Yes, Associate

### SSH into the new instance

To confirm its up and running SSH into this box
> ssh -i .ec2/pats-keypair.pem ubuntu@107.23.79.220
[image]

## Install OpenVPN

You need to download the OpenVPN software from openvpn.net. This version of the software is free to use for two users, otherwise it costs $5 per user per year, but require a minimum of 10 users so $50 per year, which is not a bad deal. https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/pricing.html [2]
From the OpenVPN machine run the following commands
> wget https://swupdate.openvpn.org/as/openvpn-as-1.8.4-Ubuntu10.amd_64.deb
> sudo dpkg –i openvpn-as-1.8.4-Ubuntu10.amd_64.deb
After the install is done you will see the admin web interface address displayed
[image]
The admin needs a password for the openvpn user run the following command to set it.
> sudo passwd openvpn
I just set mine to adminpass for test purposes.

### Configure OpenVPN

Open up OpenVPN admin web page at
https:// 107.23.79.220 :943/admin

Of course enter your static IP address for it.
[image]
You will see something like this, click on proceed anyway
[image]
The admin login page will now display. Enter the user name openvpn and the password you assigned to that user, then click Sign in
[image]
Click Agree for the license terms
[image]
Click on Server Network Settings
[image]
Enter the Elastic IP address in the hostname field
[image]
Scroll to the bottom of the page and click Save Settings

[image]
Click Update Running Server
[image]

Click on VPN settings

[image]

Scroll down to the routing section and add all your subnets to this section. I only have 2 subnets 10.0.0.0/24 and 10.0.1.0/24
[image]

Scroll down and click Save Settings
[image]
Click on Update Running Server

### Set up Client machine

Open up https:// 107.23.79.220 / in a web browser (change the IP address for your own.
[image]

Login as the openvpn user and click go
[image]
Click on “Click here to continue” This will download software you need to your system to connect to this VPN
[image]

Install the software, on a windows machine you can right click on the download and click Open
[image]
Then click Run
[image]
This window should pop up, click Yes to create the tunnel.
[image]
The web site should now report that it is up.
To test this out I am going to attempt to ssh into my instances
I have the following instances

```
10.0.0.20
10.0.1.30
10.0.0.25 NAT from aws
10.0.0.99
```

### Test Connection

From my cygwing command line:

```
ssh -i .ec2/pats-keypair.pem ubuntu@10.0.0.20
```